# How does YARN know how much resource a Spark application allocates?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a Spark cluster running on top of YARN. When I submit a spark job and look at the YARN's "cluster overview" page, "Cluster Resource Usage By Application" graph shows a fixed amount of 11.39% resource usage.

It doesn't change with how large my data is. How does YARN determine how much resource my application is using? Is it deduced from Spark configuration parameters like `--executor-cores --driver-memory --executor-memory` ? Since I have fixed values for those, is it why YARN always showing the same 11.39% usage independent of the complexity of my job?

Edit: I changed some of the configuration options. I have a 4 node cluster each having 14 vcores. Now running a spark application with 12 executors, 1 core for each executor, 600mb RAM for each executor, my application is shown as taking 3.61% in Cluster Resource Usage Per Application graph on YARN ui. How does it get calculated?

Answer (score 3):

1. How does YARN determine how much resource my application is using?

   It is not Yarn to determine how much resource application is using, it is the application that sends `resource request` to yarn resource manager(RM), and RM's scheduler allocates resources to the application. So RM knows how many containers/memory/vcores the application is using.
2. What the 11.39% resource usage means? How does it get calculated?

   There is a `ResourceCalculator` interface used to calculate the share of resource.

   - `DefaultResourceCalculator`(default) use only `memory` resource to calculate.
   - `DominantResourceCalculator` "uses the concept of *dominant resource* to compare multi-dimensional resources"
3. Why resource usage is fixed, and doesn't change with how large my data is?
4. Since I have fixed values for those, is it why YARN always showing the same 11.39% usage independent of the complexity of my job?

   Yes, the resource usage is fixed, if your application doesn't request or release more resources from RM.

   The resource usage doesn't mean real cpu/memory usage on hardware, just means RM's allocation, it will be `11.39%` even if your application is sleeping.

   Yarn use `cgroup` to control the real resource limit in Linux.

   In spark, if run application with fixed  `executor-cores/executor-memory`, the resource usage is fixed, expect `dynamicallocation` feature.